# jquery hover, mouseenter, and mouseleave not working after .appendTo

Tags: jquery

I bind the mouseenter and mouseleave event in $document.ready() like this:

```
$( ".collection_add_to" ).hover(
    function() { $(this).find( ".playlists" ).fadeIn("fast"); },
    function() { $(this).find( ".playlists" ).fadeOut("fast"); }
);
```

The user can request more search results which have the class ".collection_add_to". They are appended to the existing search results like this:

```
$.get("context/collection/", $data, function(result) {
    $( result ).appendTo( "#collection_song_items" );
    // rebind_hover();
});
```

I doubled checked that the returned results have the class ".collection_add_to". I also tried to rebind this in extra routine:

```
function rebind_hover() {
    $( ".collection_add_to" ).hover(
        function() { $(this).find( ".playlists" ).fadeIn("fast"); },
        function() { $(this).find( ".playlists" ).fadeOut("fast"); }
    );
}
```

Nothing worked, the hover event is not working anymore on the newly added items. When using the $load() function, it works. How can I make the hover-event working again on dynamically loaded content, especially when content is added with append() or appendTo()?

**edit**

Thanks to sacho on irc and Raminson:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".collection_add_to", function() {
           console.log("MOUSEENTER");
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".collection_add_to", function() {
           console.log("MOUSELEAVE");
});
```

It was not clear to me that event delegation should be done from a **node which should be higher in the DOM** than the target element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should *delegate* the event, you can use `on()` method, try the following:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', ".collection_add_to", function() { 
     $(this).find( ".playlists" ).fadeIn("fast"); 
}).on('mouseleave', ".collection_add_to", function() { 
     $(this).find( ".playlists" ).fadeOut("fast"); 
});
```

Comment: strange, the handlerIn() was not called, but the handlerOut. Thank you!

Comment: `.hover()` takes two functions but `.on()` does not, the handlerIn function will be passed as the event data

Answer (score 2):

You need to use event delegation eg.

```
$( document ).on('hover', ".collection_add_to", function(e){
    if (e.type == "mouseover") { 
        $(this).find( ".playlists" ).fadeIn("fast"); 
    }
    else if (e.type == "mouseout") { 
        $(this).find( ".playlists" ).fadeOut("fast"); 
    }
);
```

or

```
$( document ).on( "mouseover", ".collection_add_to" ,
    function() { $(this).find( ".playlists" ).fadeIn("fast"); })
  .on( "mouseout", ".collection_add_to", 
    function() { $(this).find( ".playlists" ).fadeOut("fast"); });
```

Comment: @Raminson `.hover()` takes two functions but `.on()` does not

Answer (score 0):

jQuery only can act in the original rendered `DOM` not with `DOM`-element wich are added later.

You can try [jQuery.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).